# Java RMI with SSL client authentication: obtain client x509Certificate

Tags: java, ssl, rmi, x509certificate

Is it possible to obtain a reference to connected client's x509Certificate object in Remote server implementation?

Rewrited RMISocketFactory:

```
RMISocketFactory.setSocketFactory(
        new java.rmi.server.RMISocketFactory() {
            ...
            @Override
            public ServerSocket createServerSocket(int port)
                    throws IOException {
                SSLServerSocket socket = ...
                socket.setNeedClientAuth(true);
                return socket;
            }
        });
```

Remote Object:

```
public class RMIServer extends UnicastRemoteObject implements IRMIServer {

    public RMIServer() throws RemoteException {
        super(0);
    }

    @Override
    public String foo() throws RemoteException {
        System.out.println(getClientCertificate().getSubjectDN().getName()); // something like this?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've hit on a major design flaw in RMI. It's practically impossible for an RMI server to get hold of the client certificate, or vice versa, as it's practically impossible to know which SSLSocket is in use for the current call. They should have provided a way to attach something like a HandshakeCompletionListener.